# How can I debug the uninstaller part (with CustomAction) of an installer project in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, debugging, installation

I have inherited this c# solution that includes an **ix installer project** (a bunch of .wxs files and some c# files). The uninstaller is generating an error message.

I haven't a clue what this installer project is. What are the .wxs files for? I can guess (and have successfully been able to fix some issues with the installer. I have figured out how the custom actions are set up and called etc.

But the bug in question would be so much easier to debug if I could step through it in the **debugger** - how do I do that?

**Generally:** How do I hook up the Visual Studio 2008 debugger with the installer project ("Set as Startup Project" is not an option in the Solution Explorer, tried that).?

**Specifically:** How do I debug the uninstaller? The way I see it, the uninstaller will have to use a dll not residing in the project folder (where?) and thus not really known to Visual Studio at all...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368264%28VS.85%29.aspx) article on MSDN will help.

I haven't done it recently but I think that if you add anywhere in the code Debugger.Break() statement, you will get a prompt during the install to debug the process and then you can step through it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the pages that look promising is the [WixWiki](http://wix.sourceforge.net/).

I found this on the wikipedia page for [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX).